# Remove from the beginning of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector of the following data structure

```
struct Rule {
        int m_id = -1;
        std::wstring name;
        double angle;
    };

std::vector<Rule>& topPriorityRules;
```

and I am erasing the first element of the vector using

```
topPriorityRules.erase(topPriorityRules.begin());
```

Is there any other good alternative for removing elements from the front of a `std::vecor`?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: not possible. my vector doesn't have pop_front. It's vector or Custom struct.

Comment: Something else is going on, because it should be possible.

Comment: @ВиталикБушаев std::vector doesn't have pop_front().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. struct Rule ok, what is ScanRule. What do you assign to topPriorityRules ? You have 622 rep and you don't know how to post question.

Comment: You have a missing semicolon from the end of your `struct` definition.

Comment: my struct - Rule has no overloading for iterator. 

It says no instance of overloading function std::Vector....

Comment: @acraig5075 you're right, my bad.

Comment: You are creating a vector reference rather than a vector and you put in a different `struct` name. Maybe remove the `&` giving: `std::vector<Rule> topPriorityRules;`.

Comment: You have another missing semicolon on the end of your function call.

Comment: @Galik
I need to remove from the reference.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Given

```
std::vector<Rule>& topPriorityRules;
```

The correct way to remove the first element of the referenced vector is

```
topPriorityRules.erase(topPriorityRules.begin());
```

which is exactly what you suggested.

> Looks like i need to do iterator overloading.

There is no need to overload an iterator in order to erase first element of `std::vector`.

---

P.S. Vector (dynamic array) is probably a wrong choice of data structure if you intend to erase from the front.

Comment: If you have a std::vector<Rule *> and you erase one of the indices you are just deleting the pointer, correct? To stop a memory leak something else must have that pointer or delete via "delete topPriorityRules[0];" and then "topPriorityRules.erase(topPriorityRules.begin());", right?

Comment: @BradB. if the pointer points to a dynamically allocated object, and the pointer owns that object, then yes, you have to delete the object before removing the pointer. It's a bad idea to use bare pointers that own memory.

Comment: @BradB. I would create a vector of `shared_ptr<>()` to make sure they get deleted as required without the need to be explicit in each instance.

Comment: All other things being equal, how about this?

`std::vector<Rule*> tmp(topPriorityRules.begin()+1, topPriorityRules.end());
topPriorityRules.swap(tmp);`

Answer (score 23):

Three suggestions:

1. Use `std::deque` instead of `std::vector` for better performance in your specific case and use the method `std::deque::pop_front()`.
2. Rethink (I mean: delete) the `&` in `std::vector<ScanRule>& topPriorityRules;`
3. Use `std::vector::erase()` (see Caleth's comment below).

Comment: why i am not getting pop_front for my vector?

Comment: `vector::erase` doesn't reallocate, it moves the elements after the one(s) being erased. so erasing the front element moves everything else.

Comment: @VCSEL Why std::duque and not std::queue?